# FFMPEG command to SpeedUp/SlowDown a video to a specific time

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to figure out how to write a filter for ffmpeg to take a set of videos and make them all the same time length.

For example I have a video that is 35 seconds and a video 15 seconds, but I want both the 2 videos to be 30seconds long.

I know i can use the setpts filter to speed up or slow down a video, but truthfully I don't understand filter. I know setpts is "Change the PTS (presentation timestamp) of the input frames." Though I don't think this correct filter to use as I think it applies to the time length of the frame and nothing to do with the time length of the video.

Comment: Filters don't have information on stream duration, so that has to be separately found out and then setpts invoked with an expression that uses that info.

Comment: So use `ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams XXXX.mp4`
Get the duration of the video stream. Divide the target time by duration of the existing video Which should go like this then:
`ffmpeg -i XXXX.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=(30/$SOURCEDURATION)*PTS" output.mp4`

I had hoped to be able to do it in a 1 shot line a batch file.

Comment: Not possible to do it in one command; you have to do some scripting. If your code answers your question, please use the button below to post your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Say your input file is `input.mp4` and output is `output.mp4`. You want `output.mp4` to be approximately 30 seconds long.

Here's a command you can run:

```bash
INPUT_FILE=input.mp4 && \
OUTPUT_FILE=output.mp4 && \
OUTPUT_DURATION=30 && \
CURRENT_DURATION=$(ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams -i "${INPUT_FILE}" | grep 'duration=' | head -n 1 | sed 's/duration=//') && \
echo "Found current duration ${CURRENT_DURATION} seconds" && \
SPEEDUP=$(( $CURRENT_DURATION / $OUTPUT_DURATION )) && \
echo "Processing conversion with speedup ${SPEEDUP}x" && \
ffmpeg \
    -hide_banner \
    -v warning \
    -i "${INPUT_FILE}" \
    -filter:v "setpts=PTS/${SPEEDUP}" \
    -filter:a "atempo=${SPEEDUP}" \
    "${OUTPUT_FILE}" && \
echo "Done! File written to ${OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

Let's break it down. First, we find the file duration with:

```bash
ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams -i "${INPUT_FILE}" | grep 'duration=' | head -n 1 | sed 's/duration=//'
```

We are getting the duration with `ffprobe`, then extracting the right number from the output with a combination of `grep`, `head`, and `sed`.

Next, we divide this quantity by 30 using:

```bash
$(( $CURRENT_DURATION / $OUTPUT_DURATION ))
```

We plug this into the `-filter:v "setpts=PTS/..."` to give us the correct video time scaling for speedup or slowdown. And finally we use `-filter:a "atempo=..."` to get the equivalent audio scaling.

Also note that the `-hide_banner -v warning` is simply to reduce logging information but you can remove it if you want.

---

Edit 1: Added audio time stretching as well, using `atempo` filter

Comment: thanks for the clear answer! I tried this but it seems that the audio track is not changed so no longer matches the video.  How can this be modified so the audio is also sped up? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. Let me update the command. The solution is to use `-filter:a "atempo=$SPEEDUP"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem with SPEEDUP and macos zsh not allowing floating point so I changed to

```
SPEEDUP=$(printf "%.2f" $(echo "scale=3; $CURRENT_DURATION / $OUTPUT_DURATION" | bc)) && \
```

This allows for a 2 place floating point with rounding up or down as appropriate.